# Repeat Bitmap in drawBitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I tried repeat Bitmap, but is not Repeat,

```
    private Bitmap dot;
    Paint p;
public view(Context context) {
    super(context);
    dot= BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dot);
    p = new Paint();
    p.setShader(new BitmapShader(dot, TileMode.REPEAT, TileMode.REPEAT));
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawBitmap(dot, 0, 0, p);
}
```

any other idea?
unless using a BitmapDrawable.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
canvas.drawBitmap
```

call

```
canvas.drawRect(0, 0,  getWidth(), getHeight(), p)
```